# How to remove in Java the Margin of page with iTexPdf using HTMLConverter

Tags: java, html, css, itext

I tried, with padding: 0, margin 0 in the body, tried setting the doc() with setMargin but nothing works

Comment: Please share your pivotal code and an example PDF to illustrate the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Document.setMargins() doesn’t change the margin for already generated pages. Try to use setImmediateFlush and relayout() method as suggested below.

```
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(ms);
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
converterProperties.SetImmediateFlush(false);
 //Pass the sample html file
Document document=HtmlConverter.ConvertToDocument(bodyHTML, pdfDocument, 
converterProperties);
document.SetMargins(50, 50, 50, 50);
document.Relayout();
document.Close();
```